# When I try to install Pygame through Terminal it gives me this: error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal, pygame

I have a mac running on `Catalina`. I am very new to `python` and using terminal.

I have `python` installed and I am trying to install `Pygame`. I was trying to install it through this command:

```
-m pip install Pygame==1.9.3
```

Comment: Please provide more context; what is the error message, which other commands have you tried? Because `pip install pygame==1.9.3` should be the correct command

Comment: You need to put ```py -m pip install pygame==1.9.3``` or ```python -m pip install pygame==1.9.3```. The first only works if ```python``` is in path as ```py```, but both will work anywhere while just using ```pip install pygame===1.9.3``` only works in the directory where pip is.

Comment: I did this and it said no module named pip

Answer (score 0):

You have to first install `pip` by using one of the following:

For Python 3

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

For Python 2

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

Then you have to run `python -m pip install pygame==1.9.3` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I used this command and it worked for me:

```
python -m pip install pygame
```

I worked on macOS High Sierra and Windows 10

**EDIT:** To install pip, go to https://python.org/downloads. Then download the latest version of python. Go through the installation until you get to the page where there is a button that says "customize". Click it. A menubar should pop up. Check the box next to "Install or upgrade pip". Then install python. Pip should automatically be installed and you should be able to use the command above. Here is a helpful link: https://cs.hofstra.edu/docs/pages/guides/InstallingPygame.html, scroll to where it says "Procedure (Mac OS X)".

**EDIT 2**: The command above is for python2, to install pygame for python3, execute this command in a terminal:

```
python3 -m pip install pygame
```